# Playing movie in Potraitmode in iphone using MPMoviePlayerController Class

Tags: objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

Is it possible to play the movie in potrait mode using MPMoviePlayerController Class ?

Any suggestions or any alternative methods for achieving this ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is on way of doing it: [Play iPhone Movies in Portrait Mode with MPMoviePlayerController using Public API’s](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/video/play-movies-in-portrait-mode-with-mpmovieplayercontroller-using-public-apis.html)

Maybe it is useful for you!